# Getting the same geolocation Google Maps provides for a user?

Tags: android

Are there any best practices for an app to get the same geo location as the Google Maps app?

For example, my app lists nearby Sprockets based on a user's geolocation. Often the geolocation I come up with is different than what the Google Maps app comes up with (which is often more accurate).

We can kind of do this if we have a MapActivity and use MyOverlay - this should give us the same location google maps would show - but we always need to display a map to use this. I'm almost considering just hosting a hidden map on my activity in order to use MyOverlay and grab better location updates! Any more sane way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you try, post it to be able to compare against the SDK.

Comment: The google maps app code isn't public though (not part of the sdk), so we can't see what strategy they're using the plot the user's position. If the maps app code is published somewhere, that'd be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Android has a full location API. This is what the map system uses.

Comment: Yes the location API just gives you changes in location from the providers you're subscribed to - but it's up to the developer to decide how to use these updates - which often times comes out differently than what the maps app shows. I'd just like to know how the maps app implements this really.

Answer (score 0):

A good direction to look is the open-source [Foursquare app](http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/)'s [location code](http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/browse/#hg/main/src/com/joelapenna/foursquared/location) if you're looking to manage location reports from multiple providers (GPS, network, etc.) and balance freshness and so forth. IMO their solution is a bit overarchitected for most needs, but the basic ideas are pretty easy to grok from it.